# «Ходячие мертвецы» — это оксюморон?

Tags: выбор-слов

Существует один очень популярный американский сериал, который называется The Walking Dead («Ходячие мертвецы»). Собственно говоря, возник вопрос: а это оксюморон ли? С одной стороны, и так всё понятно: мертвецы не могут ходить. Если бы название было бы другим (скажем, «Ходячие зомбари» или что-то такое), то вопроса бы не было. Но тут ведь именно *мертвецы*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражение "Ходячие мертвецы" нe что иное, как оксюморон. Оно построено на сочетании противоречивых понятий: ходячий и мертвый. В ФСРЛЯ( Фразеологический словарь русского литературного языка) есть выражение: живой (ходячий мертвец). Хотя в фильме имеются в виду, скорее всего, зомби.

Comment: Да, там именно зомби.

Comment: " Серж, "не что иное, как оксюморон"